# How to fix ? on the link instead of /

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, hyperlink

I want to link my '`name`' to other page by '`/nameID`'.

For example: `<a href='./2'>number 2</a>`

I have tried:

```
@foreach($adverts as $advert) 
  {{link_to_route('adverts', $advert->name, array($advert->id))}} 
@endforeah
```

It returns me: `<a href="http://localhost:8000/?2">`, but I need `<a href="http://localhost:8000/2">`.

Where am I wrong?

More details:

models/advert.php

```
class advert extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'adverts';
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'adverts', 'uses'=>'advertsController@index'));
Route::get('/{id}', array('as'=>'advert', 'uses'=>'advertsController@info'));
```

controllers/advertsController.php

```
public function index() {
    return View::make('adverts.index')
               ->with('adverts', advert::All());
}
public function info($id) {
    return View::make('adverts.info')
               ->with('advert', advert::find($id));
}
```

When I change the second route to `'as'=>'adverts'` then it works fine. But I have no idea why it works. If I understand clearly, `'as'=>'advert'` is only a specific name of the route, isn’t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using the wrong route. You should be using `advert` (singular), as that’s the route that takes a parameter. If you try and use the index route (`adverts`), it’ll tack any additional parameters on as a query string.

So given you have these routes:

```
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'adverts', 'uses'=>'advertsController@index'));
Route::get('/{id}', array('as'=>'advert', 'uses'=>'advertsController@info'));
```

If you want to link to an individual advert, you need to use this:

```
{{ link_to_route('advert', $advert->name, array($advert->id)) }}
```

Also, you may want to take a look at [resource controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). They’re perfect for situations like these, where you want one route/view to list a resource, and another route/view to view details of a particular resource.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your route definition and add a path parameter:

```
 Route::get('/', array('as'=>'adverts', 'uses'=>'advertsController@index'));
 Route::get('/{id}', array('as'=>'advert', 'uses'=>'advertsController@info'));

 {{link_to_route('advert', array('id' => $advert->id))}}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your help. I have changed my question for more specification. Can you help me? pls

Comment: It worked because the second route definition was overwriting the first one. Anyway, you should have 2 routes defined: adverts that shows all ads and advert that shows ad by id and then make sure you use correct one in link_to_route. You could also have a look at resource controllers as Martin suggests